# Improvements on column renaming using a mapping table

Tags: r

I was wondering whether I could use more data.table functions rather than using for loops in the following piece of code:

```
library(data.table)

n1 <- data.table(A = c(1:5),
                B = c(1:5), 
                C = c(1:5))

n2 <- data.table(D = c(1:5),
                E = c(1:5), 
                F = c(1:5))

n3 <- data.table(G = c(10:15),
                H = c(10:15), 
                I = c(10:15),
                K = c(10:15))

m <- data.table(name1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
                name2 = c("E", "F", "D"),
                name3 = c("I", "H", "G"))

naming_convention <- function(l, m, index = 1){
  if (index > length(l)){
    stop("Indices cannot exceed the number of dataframes in the list.")
  }
  
  if (ncol(m) != length(l)){
    stop("Columns in mapping matrix, need to match the number of dataframes in the list.")
  }
  
  new_names <- m[, eval(index), with = FALSE][[1]]
  
  if (length(new_names) != ncol(l[[index]])){
    stop("Not all columns are defined of the reference matrix.")
  }
  
  for(i in c(1:ncol(m))){
    if(i == index){
      next
    }
    temp <- l[[i]]
    setnames(temp, old = m[[i]], new = new_names)
    l[[i]] <- temp[,..new_names]
  }
  return(l)
}

l <- list(n1, n2, n3)
naming_convention(l, m, 1)
```

Examples:
naming_convention(l, m, 1)

should rename all columns to A, B, C of all the data tables in the list, based on the mapping presented in m matrix. For example, in the second matrix, the E would be mapped to an A, F to be mapped to B and D to be mapped to C. For the third table, I mapped to A, H mapped to B, G mapped to C.

Note that if we change the index to 2, `naming_convention(l, m, 2)`, all column names should be renamed to E, F, D. So for the first table it would rename A to E, B to F and C to D.